# How to obtain gradients of Stable Baselines 3 models while training?

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I currently use Stable Baselines 3 to train a reinforcement learning SAC agent on a custom environment. I would like to plot the mean of all calculated gradients of the model while it is training. There are some unexpected drops in the performance of the agent and I want to exclude the possibility of exploding gradients.

To have some insight into the training of the model, Stable Baselines 3 allows you to create custom callbacks (there are also existing callbacks that allow you to save the model during training). Usually, to get to the gradients you call up the parameters of the model after the backpropagation but before the model is updated.

Unfortunately, when I call the parameters with the function `get_parameters()` (in the custom callback loop `_on_rollout_end`, which should be called right before the update) there are no gradients. So I assume the gradients have not yet been calculated.

**Is there a way to get the gradients of Stable Baselines 3 models while it is training?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.